# Binding Dictionary to WPF toolkit Chart

Tags: wpf, binding, dictionary, charts, wpftoolkit

Here is my code for binding a dictionary item to a Chart control. I keep getting the following error:

**"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"**

Here is my Code:

```
foreach (DataRow drow in objD0s.Tables[0].Rows)// Adding values from a dataset to dictionary    
     {


         string strvalue = Convert.ToString(drow["Chemical Name"]);
         string doublevalue = Convert.ToString(drow["Global Warming"]);
         Cdata.Add(Convert.ToString(strvalue), Convert.ToDouble(doublevalue));

     }
     ColumnSeries colSeries = ChartChemImpact.Series[0] as ColumnSeries;     

         ((ColumnSeries)ChartChemImpact.Series[0]).DataContext = Cdata;
         colSeries.ItemsSource = myDataTable0.DefaultView;
         colSeries.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("[Chemical Name]");
         colSeries.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("[Global Warming]");

  }
```

XAM

```
 chartingToolkit:Chart Name="ChartChemImpact" Title="Chart Title"   Width="384"            Height="280">
   <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries DependentValuePath="Key"  IndependentValuePath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="colSeries" />
  </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Please help :(

Comment: The dataset has two columns 'Chemical Name' and 'Global Warming'

Comment: 1. ValueBindings receive their values from the ItemsSource property, which isn't a dictionary (but strange class DefaultView). 2. `IndependentValueBinding` is the same as the `IndependentValuePath`, it is applied to an item, not to a collection. So the last three lines of the code file are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found the mistake. There are binding and value paths in the xaml, but they are replaced in the code.

I would remove those lines, so here is the result:

```
foreach (DataRow drow in objD0s.Tables[0].Rows)// Adding values from a dataset to dictionary    
{
     string strvalue = Convert.ToString(drow["Chemical Name"]);
     string doublevalue = Convert.ToString(drow["Global Warming"]);
     Cdata.Add(Convert.ToString(strvalue), Convert.ToDouble(doublevalue));
}

((ColumnSeries)ChartChemImpact.Series[0]).DataContext = Cdata;
//And that's the end of the function, no more code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I guess its some other issue here, I still keep getting the same error. The problem might be in the XAML code.

Comment: @MangoTable I haven't noticed the xaml. Yes, change the attribute `DependentValuePath="Key"` to `DependentValuePath="Value"` and the `IndependentValuePath` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Changing this line: "((ColumnSeries)ChartChemImpact.Series[0]).DataContext = Cdata;" to simply colSeries.ItemsSource=CData;  worked for me.